# Problema ao fixar coluna lateral quando o scroll for maior que a sua altura

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tenho um layout com uma div principal e dentro dela 2 divs, cada qual sendo uma coluna:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#principal{
   display: flex;
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
}

#conteudo{
   width: calc(100% - 330px);
   height: 1500px;
   background-color: orange;
   margin-right: 30px;
}

#lateral{
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 1100px;
   background-color: red;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}

#lateral span{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
   <div id="conteudo">
      conteúdo
   </div>
   <div id="lateral">
      coluna lateral
      <span>fim da coluna lateral</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Ao rolar pra baixo, repare que a div à direita (vermelha) tem uma altura menor do que a div à esquerda (laranja).

O objetivo é que a coluna vermelha acompanhe o scroll da página normalmente, mas, quando o seu final (borda inferior), assim que entrar na área da janela do navegador, ela pare de rolar junto à janela e se torne fixa (mesmo comportamento da coluna lateral direita do Facebook em desktop); e ao rolar o documento de volta pra cima, ela volte ao normal acompanhando novamente o scroll da janela.

Até consegui fazer a lógica programática com JavaScript, porém o problema é que ao alterar a propriedade `position` da div para `fixed`, ela foge da div principal, pois o valor `fixed` é relativo ao body, e não ao seu contêiner, desvirtuando o layout.

Veja:

```js
window.onscroll = function(){

   // posição do scroll
   var scrol = window.pageYOffset;
   
   // altura do documento
   var w_alt = window.innerHeight;
   
   // pega a lateral
   var lat = document.getElementById("lateral");

   // altura coluna lateral
   var l_alt = lat.clientHeight;

   // se o valor do scroll for maior do que a diferença
   // da altura da lateral pela altura da janela
   if(scrol > l_alt - w_alt){
      
      // torna a lateral fixa
      lat.style.position = "fixed";
      
   }else{

      // volta para relative
      lat.style.position = "relative";

   }
   
}
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#principal{
   display: flex;
   width: 80%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
}

#conteudo{
   width: calc(100% - 330px);
   height: 1500px;
   background-color: orange;
   margin-right: 30px;
}

#lateral{
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 1100px;
   background-color: red;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}

#lateral span{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
   <div id="conteudo">
      conteúdo
   </div>
   <div id="lateral">
      coluna lateral
      <span>fim da coluna lateral</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Como poderia fazer para que essa div ficasse fixa da forma acima mas sem sair da sua posição dentro da div `#principal`, ou seja, que ela simplesmente ficasse fixa quando o scroll atingir sua altura?

> Obs.: necessário ser em JavaScript puro.

Comment: Qual o suporte para navegador? Tem que funcionar em explorer? e edge mobile?

Comment: Oi @AndersonHenrique! Não tem problema com suporte. Funcionando no Chrome já tá ótimo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sam eu tenho uma solução para vc. Não sei se era exatamente o que vc queria, mas vai resolver apenas com JS. Talvez seja possível fazer no CSS, mas como já tem o `script` coloquei o `style` nele mesmo.

Como vc falou, o elemento com `position:fixed` fica relativo ao `body`, porém o seu `container` tem 80% de largura do `body`, logo vc tem 10% de margem a esquerda e 10% a direita. Então a ideia é que ao mesmo tempo que vc seta o `position:fixed` eu tb seto o `marginRight` de 10%, com isso ele não "foge" do `container` pai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o código

```js
window.onscroll = function () {

  // posição do scroll
  var scrol = window.pageYOffset;

  // altura do documento
  var w_alt = window.innerHeight;

  // pega a lateral
  var lat = document.getElementById("lateral");

  // altura coluna lateral
  var l_alt = lat.clientHeight;

  // se o valor do scroll for maior do que a diferença
  // da altura da lateral pela altura da janela
  if (scrol > l_alt - w_alt) {

    // torna a lateral fixa
    lat.style.position = "fixed";
    lat.style.marginRight = "10%";

  } else {

    // volta para relative
    lat.style.position = "relative";
    lat.style.marginRight = "initial";

  }

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#principal {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#conteudo {
  width: calc(100% - 330px);
  height: 1500px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#lateral {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 1100px;
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#lateral span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="principal">
  <div id="conteudo">
    conteúdo
  </div>
  <div id="lateral">
    coluna lateral
    <span>fim da coluna lateral</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tão simples e eu não pensei nisso rs.. valeu!

Comment: @Sam era tão simples que até fiquei na dúvida se era isso mesmo que vc queria rss. []´s

Comment: As vezes as coisas mais simples fogem à nossa percepção. :D